# Android How I Can AppWidget Play Gif?

Tags: android, android-widget

Using glide library.
It was like normal picture.
I tried the glide library but it did not work.
Using glide library.
It was like normal picture.
I tried the glide library but it did not work.

```
 public class NewAppWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {
    private static AppWidgetTarget appWidgetTarget;

static void updateAppWidget(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
                            int appWidgetId) {

    CharSequence widgetText = NewAppWidgetConfigureActivity.loadTitlePref(context, appWidgetId);
    // Construct the RemoteViews object
    RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.new_app_widget);
    views.setTextViewText(R.id.appwidget_text, widgetText);
    RemoteViews rv = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.new_app_widget);

    appWidgetTarget = new AppWidgetTarget( context, rv, R.id.imageView, appWidgetId );

    Glide
            .with( context.getApplicationContext() ) // safer!
            .load("https://i.giphy.com/l4FGq1K2WUMWYSisw.gif")
            .asBitmap()
            .into(appWidgetTarget);
    pushWidgetUpdate(context, rv);

    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, rv);
}
public static void pushWidgetUpdate(Context context, RemoteViews rv) {
    ComponentName myWidget = new ComponentName(context, NewAppWidget.class);
    AppWidgetManager manager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
    manager.updateAppWidget(myWidget, rv);
}
@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    // There may be multiple widgets active, so update all of them
    for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {
        updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetId);

        RemoteViews rv = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.new_app_widget);

        appWidgetTarget = new AppWidgetTarget( context, rv, R.id.imageView, appWidgetIds );

        Glide
                .with( context.getApplicationContext() ) // safer!
                .load("https://i.giphy.com/l4FGq1K2WUMWYSisw.gif")
                .asBitmap()
                .into(appWidgetTarget);
        pushWidgetUpdate(context, rv);
    }

}
```

My English is bad, I apologize already, I can tell you that I can tell.
Thanks

Comment: you can achive it my using this https://github.com/aatishmittal194/carouselNotification

Answer (score 0):

`ImageView` does not display the animation of an animated GIF. There is no widget that can go onto an app widget that will play the animation of an animated GIF.

Comment: this guy did gif in remoteview https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.quantumgraph.demo  ,Any Idea about how it done